# Using *arg in to assign value to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, args

I'd like to define a DataFrame using *arg. I want to use the special syntax *args pass a variable number of arguments to a data frame column as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

def test(*args):
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for arg in args:
        data[str(arg)] = arg
    print(data)

test(1, 'a', 'b', 2)
```

I expect that the output is a data Frame with the columns `[1, a, b, 2]` and the respective values. But I only get an empty DataFrame.

Comment: test([1, 'a', 'b', 2]) try to call with this

Comment: @wonka: i get a data frame of dimension (4*1), instead of (1*4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def test(*args):
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for arg in args:
        data[str(arg)] = [arg]
    print(data)

test(1, 'a', 'b', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
import pandas as pd

def test(*args):
    di = dict((str(x), x) for x in args)
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([di])
    print(data)
```

> SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
test(1, 'a', 'b', 2)

   1  2  a  b
0  1  2  a  b
```

Comment: Or possibly: `def f(*args): return pd.DataFrame(data=[args], columns=[str(col) for col in args])`